# Who actually were demons (Rakshash) and Danav mentioned in Ramayana, Mahabharata and other purans?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, ramayana, rakshasa

Were they different species or just human following adharma?
We read in puranas that they were powerful, mayavi, had body features like animals.   I am confused.

Tulsidasji says in Ramcharitmanas that who follows adharma is a nishachar ( demon).

What are the differences between human, Rakshasa and Danava?

Comment: Do you want to know differences between Rakshasa and Danavas?

Comment: @the destroyer I just want to know difference between human and rakshash , danav etc